# What is the Probability that 4 Cards are Less than 1 Cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

From a 52 card deck, the dealer deals 4 cards to player 1 and 1 card to player 2. What is the probability that player 2's one card is greater in value than all of player 1's cards. Can someone tell me the general approach I should take?

My work so far:

$P(Player\quad 2\quad Winning)\quad =\quad \frac { 4*{ _{ 8 }{ C }_{ 4 }+4*_{ 12 }{ C }_{ 4 }+4*_{ 16 }{ C }_{ 4 }+...+4*_{ 48 }{ C }_{ 4 } } }{ _{ 52 }{ C }_{ 5 } } *\frac { 1 }{ 5 } =Around\quad17\%$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altogether a set of $5$ cards is dealt. In order for Player $2$ to win, the set must contain only one card of its highest denomination, and Player $2$ must get that card. Thus, Player $2$ has one chance in $5$ of winning **if** there is a unique highest card in the set, and no chance of winning if there is not a unique highest card in the set. How many sets have a unique highest card?

You can calculate this in at least two ways. One is to count separately for each possible highest value. For instance, there are $4\binom84$ sets in which a three is the highest card: each contains $4$ cards that are aces or twos, and one of the threes.

Another is to count by the distribution of denominations. How many are there in which there are $5$ different denominations? How many are there in which there are $4$ different denominations, one appearing twice? And so on. For instance, there are $\binom{13}4$ ways to pick $4$ denominations, $3$ ways to choose one of the bottom $3$ to get the fifth card, $4$ ways to pick each of the three singletons, and $\binom42$ ways to pick the doubleton, for a total of

$$\binom{13}4\cdot3\cdot4^3\cdot\binom64$$

sets.

Comment: I used your first method but for some reason I don't think my answers correct, can you help me correct it (I edited my post)?

Comment: @WorldBright: You’re missing a term $4\binom44=4$ in the numerator, but otherwise that’s what I get, with probability about $0.1708$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much.

Comment: @WorldBright: You’re very welcome.